# System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute

Tags: .net, configuration, system

```
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("s")]
```

The string `"s"` must be constant. How can I pass a variable string?

I mean I want it like this:

```
[global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute(s1+"s")]
```

and `s1` is a string.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. Like the error message says, a parameter to an attribute must be a constant value, known at compile time.

Comment: ok is there a way or another attribute which does the same role and takes variable string?

Comment: or can i make if else condition?

Comment: It's not a limitation of the DefaultSettingValueAttribute - the compiler will only let you pass a value known at compile time to an attribute. The values you pass in are compiled into the assembly. Maybe you need to do something in your settings class constructor?